# Using harmony flags with StrongLoop Loopback Arc

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, strongloop

I'm trying out the creation of an application built on top of StrongLoop's Loopback. I prefer to use ES6 features if possible, but when using Arc to start the server, it chokes on ES6 syntax.

Is there a way to configure an application to use the Node harmony flags when starting through `arc`? I'd prefer to not use a transpiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the "start" script to "node --harmony ." in your package.json.  Like so:

```
"scripts": {
   "pretest": "jshint .",
   "start": "node --harmony ."
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem that `arc` uses npm scripts. Legitimate if you are manually starting without that tool, though. I ended up abandoning loopback because of its lack of flexibility and am doing what you suggested.

Comment: It worked for me.  I threw in a generator and ran `arc` and it wouldn't build.  After adding in the script and running `arc` again, it built successfully (in the GUI).

Comment: Awesome, so `arc` uses an npm `start` script if it exists? Good to know.